# IOS Swift Cocoapods - install and use couchbase library

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, couchbase, couchbase-lite

i want to use couchbase in my ios swift app and therefore installed the couchbase pod into my project.

Also added all header files to the Bridging-Header file, but the compiler cant resolve these links to the header files and is unable to find the class CBLManager.

Bridging-Header File - attempt 1

```
#import "CouchbaseLiteListener.framework/Headers/CBLListener.h"
#import "CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLAttachment.h"
#import "CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLAuthenticator.h"
#import "CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLDatabase.h"
#import "CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLDatabaseChange.h"
#import "CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLDocument.h"
#import "CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLGeometry.h"
#import "CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLJSON.h"
#import "CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLManager.h"
#import "CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLModel.h"
#import "CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLModelFactory.h"
#import "CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLQuery.h"
#import "CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLQuery+FullTextSearch.h"
#import "CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLQuery+Geo.h"
#import "CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLReplication.h"
#import "CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLRevision.h"
#import "CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLUITableSource.h"
#import "CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLView.h"
#import "CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CouchbaseLite.h"
#import "CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/MYDynamicObject.h"
```

Bridging-Header File - attempt 2

```
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/Frameworks/CouchbaseLiteListener.framework/Headers/CBLListener.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/Frameworks/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLAttachment.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/Frameworks/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLAuthenticator.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/Frameworks/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLDatabase.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/Frameworks/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLDatabaseChange.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/Frameworks/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLDocument.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/Frameworks/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLGeometry.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/Frameworks/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLJSON.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/Frameworks/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLManager.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/Frameworks/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLModel.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/Frameworks/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLModelFactory.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/Frameworks/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLQuery.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/Frameworks/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLQuery+FullTextSearch.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/Frameworks/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLQuery+Geo.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/Frameworks/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLReplication.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/Frameworks/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLRevision.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/Frameworks/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLUITableSource.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/Frameworks/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLView.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/Frameworks/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CouchbaseLite.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/Frameworks/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/MYDynamicObject.h"
```

I allready did the same with AFNetworking and this is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution

```
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/CouchbaseLiteListener.framework/Headers/CBLListener.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLAttachment.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLAuthenticator.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLDatabase.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLDatabaseChange.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLDocument.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLGeometry.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLJSON.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLManager.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLModel.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLModelFactory.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLQuery.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLQuery+FullTextSearch.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLQuery+Geo.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLReplication.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLRevision.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLUITableSource.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CBLView.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/CouchbaseLite.h"
#import "Pods/couchbase-lite-ios/CouchbaseLite.framework/Headers/MYDynamicObject.h"
```

Comment: No Need of entire path on headr file try lik #import "CouchbaseLite/CouchbaseLite.h" "CouchbaseLite.h" contains all classes header files here.

Answer (score 0):

Using the couchbase-lite-ios 1.2.0 pod, I was able to use a single line in my bridging header:

```
#import "couchbase-lite-ios/CouchbaseLite/CouchbaseLite.h"
```